# Static array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, performance, static, julia, allocation

I have functions which are called many times and require temporary arrays. Rather than array allocation happening every time the function is called, I would like the temporary to be statically allocated once.

How do I create a statically allocated array in Julia, with function scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let's assume that your function is called foo with an argument `x` and your array is just 100 hundred elements (each of which is a 64-bit value) with one dimension. Then you can create a scope around that function

```
let
    global foo
    let A = Array{Int64}(100)
    function foo(x)
        # do your tasks
    end
end
```

`A` should be a let variable since it would overwrite any other global `A`.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the temp array as a reference in a class:

```
type MyWrapper
    thetmparray
    thefunction::Function
    function MyWrapper(outertmp::Array)
        this = new(outertmp)
        this.thefunction = function()
            #use this.thetmparray or outertmp
        end
        return this
    end
end
```

This away you can [avoid global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109) and (in the future) have a per-executor/thread/process/machine/etc temp array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `let` block or partial application (I prefer this approach for such a case):

```
function bind_array(A::Array) 
    function f(x)
        A = A*x
    end
end
```

Now you can bind a private array to every new "instance" of your `f`:

```
julia> f_x = bind_array(ones(1,2))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> display(f_x(2))
1x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.0  2.0

julia> display(f_x(3))
1x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 6.0  6.0

julia> f_y = bind_array(ones(3,2))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> display(f_y(2))
3x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.0  2.0
 2.0  2.0
 2.0  2.0

julia> display(f_y(3))
3x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 6.0  6.0
 6.0  6.0
 6.0  6.0
```